# Running python3 manage.py runserver but not seeing any requests

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I activated my virtual environment with `source env/bin/activate`, and then started my server with `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`.

I have made sure I have the following in my `settings.py`:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xx.xx.xx.xxx', 'mywebsite.org']
```

I start the server and it outputs :

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 28, 2019 - 21:40:33
Django version 2.0.7, using settings 'app.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:80/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But, I visit "mywebsite.org" and it outputs

```
> Index of / 
> Name    Last modified     Size  Description cgi-bin  
> 2018-08-23 07:26  -
```

The homepage of my website normally appears when I visit "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", so how can I get that to appear?

I'm using a Mac

Comment: This likely means that there is something else that is also running on port 80 on the server.  You can find out wha else is running by using `lsof -i :80`

Comment: @2ps I ran that line and it prints nothing (nothing at all) :/

Comment: you may have to prefix the command with `sudo` if you ar e not running it as root.

Comment: it's still printing nothing..even when I've started the server on the port (?)

Comment: Actually, I can see the webpage sometimes randomly and then I quit the server and start it again and it's back to the /index thing...

Comment: What have you done to point mywebsite.org at that server? Note also, runserver is not suitable for use in production.